# blackberry signed keys not working after mylaptop restart

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde, blackberry-storm, blackberry-playbook

i am getting signed keys to my mail.

i got 3 csi files and fallow the steps to install these keys which are give in main.

eveything is fine but after restarting my pc i can't able to sign project.

it again ask signed keys,i am trying to reinstall the same 3 .csi files then i got error

unable to register client 3707997321 because there are no more regestration attempts.

i am trying in same sysytem.is there any possibilities to work these and where can i found these installed keys.

can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to reinstall the keys you will get that error.

So the issue is after restarting the PC, you are not able to sign again.

There could be many reasons for this issue. But one **possible reason** is you installed keys using one version of Eclipse and now you are trying to run & sign another installed version of Eclipse.

For example, you installed keys using an Eclipse which is installed in c:\Eclipse. Now you are using an Eclipse which is installed in c:\Eclipse_new_path.

Comment: Thank u jomy john,But i have only one eclipse in my pc,i am getting error  in that same eclipse

Comment: Info about installed keys can be found in C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde\vmTools files names are sigtool.csk & sigtool.db . Check these files are existed and not zero size.

Comment: NO, i have only signaturetool.jar file only